# Garage band: how to add marks to tracks?

Tags: garage-band

I would like to add some marks (sort of annotations) at some points (more than one) of my track. Something like the arrangements marks, but on a per-track basis. I think I can't, since I can't find any information about this. But I try to ask here.. :) Thank you

Comment: Why not split them and rename the different sections?

Comment: A side comment from myself: I use Logic now, and it has marks too, just like I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to TRACKS at the top and click on Show Arrangement tracks. It will add a track on top of the whole thing, then you rename it (right-click) and you treat it as a clip. I took it to the end of a clip and then marked the beginning of it and it kinda worked. I know what you mean, like while it's playing pressing M or something to mark on the spot, but I haven't found that yet!

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the best way.

[image: See the image below]
    _

Then you can name any of the clips whatever you want.

You could even make an extra track with empty (silent) clips and use them just to write in.

Comment: Mmm thank you but it's not what I meant. I'd like to make annotations in several points of the same track. Something like the arrangment markers, but for each track instead of global. Anyway, now I understand it's currently impossible.

Comment: Interesting...although I'd like to hear more about the difference between this solution and what you're looking for. What do per-track arrangement markers offer that this solution does not?

Comment: I'd like to be able to put more than one mark on the same waveform, for example.

Comment: for ex., minute 1: here is a special chord made this way, minute 2:33: here we should add cymbals, minute 3:20: that guitar fx had this settings, etc...

Comment: To be honest, if you want to make a note of this kind of information, so you can remember what you want to do when you come back to a project, I would just use the Notepad function, and write exactly what you have above, in other words, times and descriptions. Unfortunately you can't do this by track in Garageband (you can in Logic), but at least the notepad will be saved as part of the project.

Answer (score 1):

I know precisely what you are looking for. In Final Cut you can tap as it is playing adding markers or beats on the go to allow for precise cut and pasting etc.

Comment: How does this answer the question for GarageBand?